# Choosing commits for separate branches of one repository

Tags: git

I have a documentation project at http://readthedocs.org/, which takes source from github repo. Since I'm not sure of the syntax it might need for one or another file I created a separate branch at github to push as many commits as I need there to see the result at http://readthedocs.org/.

I would like to be able to choose commits later on and push them to `master` branch where from I will make PRs. Is there such a way or it is bad approach and there is something more appropriate for that?

Comment: sounds like you want to do a merge from a dev branch to a release branch, not sure if git has different names for that, I'm only familiar with tfs

Answer (score 2):

git cherry-pick should meet your needs.  Documentation is here: http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html

This allows you to select individual commits (from your branch) and apply them to your working tree.

Example:

```
jayray @ myrepo > git log
commit fd7aafce97949da4f80d5fd08b5d9bcc5e85b565
Date:   Mon Apr 16 16:50:52 2012 -0400

    added d

commit 9b40ed02b0d594391e81c0f19883f4bc05d8751c
Date:   Mon Apr 16 16:50:47 2012 -0400

    added c

commit 4359f39765aac74509a4ed876ba1266a2624797e
Date:   Mon Apr 16 16:50:41 2012 -0400

    added b

jayray @ myrepo > git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'

jayray @ myrepo > git cherry-pick 9b40ed02b0d594391e81c0f19883f4bc05d8751c
[master 3b78d02] added c
 0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 c
```

So this allowed me to apply a single commit from my branch to my master.  You can specify multiple commits as well.

Comment: I see, but will it work if this commits ( not from `master` ) were already pushed to github? Will I still be able to locally `cherry-pick` the commits I wan't and add them to `master` branch and then separately push them to `master` branch at github? Or it will all work if only it is maintained locally?

Comment: @Eugene yes, just get the SHA for the commit you want to cherry-pick. For this use the same 'git log' or any GUI like gitx or gitk

Comment: @Eugene: "will it work if this commits ( not from master ) were already pushed to github": you can use this to pick commits from one branch to another (such as master) irregardless if you have pushed to Github

Comment: @Eugene: "Will I still be able to locally cherry-pick..and then separately push them to master branch at github": yes, when you cherry-pick into master, this creates new commits on master.  You can then at any point push to a remote like github

Comment: Why do I always have conflicts with `cherry-pick`? i.e. I created a file on `master` branch, then commited and pushed it, next two commits where made to a new branch `dev` (on same file), but when I try to `cherry-pick`, then it always makes conflict. And even after resolving it in IDE and trying to commit to `master` branch it shows it as an empty commit.